# Due to a bug, Sonic can become unable to jump. How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Tags: technical-issues, android, sonic-the-hedgehog-2

## Background information

I've been playing Sonic the Hedgehog 2.  I'm using the [official Android build](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sega.sonic2.runner).  (I've never tried the [unofficial omni-platform version](https://github.com/Rubberduckycooly/Sonic-1-2-2013-Decompilation#readme).)

At unpredictable moments — maybe once every few hours or so — a bug gets triggered.  I'm not sure what triggers it.

When the bug has been triggered:

- I can walk left and right, as usual.
- I can look up and down, as usual.
- Unfortunately, I cannot jump.  When I tap the right half of the screen, the translucent jump button is not depressed, and my character does not jump.
- I can pause the game in the usual way.
- On the pause screen, I can try to tap "Continue", "Restart", "Settings", or "Exit".  If I try to do so, the pressed button lights up in yellow, but does nothing.  If I tap the Back button on the system navigation bar, this resumes the game successfully.

I'm not sure what triggers the bug.  And, once the bug has been triggered, I don't know of any reliable way to get the game back to normal, other than to [close the app](https://www.wikihow.tech/Close-Apps-on-Android) completely and launch it again.  So, I'll lose all the progress I've made since the last time the game [saved itself](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/400197/when-sonic-2-for-android-saves-what-information-gets-saved-and-what-doesnt).

## My question

How can I troubleshoot the problem, and get more information about what's going wrong?

## Notes

I'm running version 1.6.0 of Sonic 2 on Android 8.0.0 "Oreo" on an old LG G5.  I've enabled developer mode, and I have Android Studio installed on my computer.  I can successfully open an adb shell.